# Why is storage class not checked by compiler on overridden functions?

Tags: c++, overriding, storage-class-specifier

```
#include <iostream>

class A{
public:
  void printit(register int b) {
     std::cout<<"inside A";
  }
};

class C:public A{
public:
  void printit(int b) {
     std::cout<<"inside C";
  }
};

int main() {
C c;
c.printit(1);
return 0;
}
```

In the above code, printit is an overridden method in C without the storage class register. But, compiler still matches that and the code prints "inside C". Why is a register int matched with int?

Comment: Are you intending for this code to behave polymorphically? Because your base class does not declare the method `virtual` nor does the derived class declare the method `override` (not that the latter is technically required)

Comment: Why do you think this should behave otherwise? `register` is just an optimization hint which the compiler *may* disregard. Since this is just a suggestion to the compiler, any generic behavior derived from optimization-dependent hints would be wrong by definition.

There are a heap of more specific rules this would violate. But on the logic level to me this is the most basic problem with this assumption.

Comment: @CoryKramer I intend for C's method not override A's method. But it does, which is what I am not able to reason out.

Comment: If this is C++17, you are not allowed to use the `register` keyword anyway. If the compiler allows you to use it, then it can do whatever it wants.

Comment: How do you mean "not override"? You have object of class `C`, objects of class `C` have method `printit` (which hides `A::printit`). There is no overriding or overloading.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen is right, even if `C` had `void printit(long long b)` it would still behave the same.  Clearly the argument types are different, but the `printit` in `C` hides the `prinitit` in `A`.

Comment: Note that `register` has been removed from recent versions of the C++ standard because it is pointless. It's just a *hint* to the compiler (that it is free to ignore) and the compilers optimizer does a better job at placing variables in registers than the programmer could *anyway*.

Answer (score 6):

[C++ storage classes](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration) have never participated in overload resolution. This is for obvious reasons: storage classes modify how/where a particular variable's memory comes from. Overload resolution is about the nature of the *expressions* being used to call a function. And expressions don't really have storage classes.

Yes, an expression which denotes a variable that has a storage class could be said to have a storage class. But expressions can be various computations on variables too. Or literals. Or function return values. None of these things have storage classes.

So while you can declare that a parameter uses the `register` storage class (to the degree that `register` is still a thing in C++. C++11 deprecated this use of the keyword, and C++17 and beyond formally removed it), that doesn't mean it participates in overload resolution. It only affects how the parameter variable in question gets its memory (to the extent that `register` has any behavior at all in C++, of course).

Aside from this is the fact that, if you inherit from a base class and you create a method with the same name as a base class method, the base class methods are hidden from access unless you use a `using` declaration to bring them back. So even if storage classes somehow participated in overload resolution, your code still wouldn't work.

Answer (score 1):

The object is of type `C`, it will call the method in class `C`, it's unaware of the existence of another method in a base class. It's, in fact, unaware of the existence of a base class.

Regarding an overload using `register` in one of the parameters, it does not diferenciate the parameters because it's not a type, it's a keyword to make a variable be stored in the processor register instead of "normal" memory.

An easier way to check this is to try to overload in the same class:

```
class A {
public:
    void printit(int b);
    void printit(register int b);
};
```

You will have a compilation error:

`'void A::printit(int)' cannot be overloaded with 'void A::printit(int)'`

Note that ISO C++17 removed `register` storage specifier.